# Caching attributes in superclass

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, caching, properties

I have a class which caches some values to avoid computing them many times, for instance

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self._value = None

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self._value is None:
            self._value = # <complex code that produces value>
        return self._value
```

In this way, `self._value` is computed only once and all the other times the precomputed value is returned. So far so good.

Now, let's suppose I want to subclass `A` with class `B`. In our case class `B` will have its own method of computing `self._value` but it sometimes will need `A`'s `value`, like in this example:

```
class B(A):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a, b)

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self._value is not None:
            self._value = # <complex code that produces B's version of value>
        return self._value

    def get_old_value(self):
        return super().value  # here comes the trouble
```

Now, clearly the trouble is that if `get_old_value()` is called before `value()` it will cache `A`'s `value` forever. If `value()` is called before `get_old_value()` in the same way, `get_old_value()` will actually always return `value()`.

Of course, one could simply use `A`'s `<complex code that produces value>`, in the implementation of `get_old_value()` but that would duplicate code (which would pretty much make subclassing useless) or even wrap `<complex code that produces value>` inside another method in `A` and call that method in `get_old_value()` but this would not use caching at all.

Another way could be the following:

```
def get_old_value(self):
    result = super().value
    self._c = None
    return result
```

but that would anyway remove caching for `A`'s version of `value` and does not look clean at all. Is there any better way to accomplish this?

One thing I want to add is that in my code `A` and `B` make really sense as superclass and subclass, otherwise I would consider composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use name-mangling -- this will allow each class/subclass to maintain a private version of the variable so they don't clobber each other:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.__value = None

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.__value is None:
            self.__value = 7
        return self.__value

class B(A):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.__value = None

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.__value is None:
            self.__value = 17
        return self.__value

    def get_old_value(self):
        return super().value  # no more trouble here
```

And in use:

```
>>> b = B(1, 2)
>>> print(b.value)
17
>>> print(b.get_old_value())
7
```

Please note you now need to set `__value` in `B`'s `__init__` as well.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844612/208880) for a couple more tidbits about name-mangling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If you are interested you can find a followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917216/followup-attribute-caching-in-superclasses