# Followup: attribute caching in superclasses

Tags: python-3.x, caching, properties

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914246/caching-attributes-in-superclass). I have a class which caches an attribute for its subclasses:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._value = None

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self._value is None:
            self._value = self.complex_computation()
        return self._value

    def complex_computation(self):
        raise NotImplemented
```

Now, let's suppose I have many subclasses of `A`, each one overriding only `complex_computation()`, hence delegating the caching mechanism to the parent class. Now let's suppose one of this classes is `B` and `B` has a subclass itself, `C`:

```
class B(A):
    def complex_computation(self):
        return # B's complex computation happens here

class C(B):
    def complex_computation(self):
        return # C's complex computation happens here
```

However, let's assume that `C` also wants to return `B`'s `value` still making use of the caching mechanism defined in class `A`. `C` could add the following method:

```
def parent_complex_computation(self):
    return super().value  # this does not work
```

As described in the previous question, this would not work. In fact, if one accesses `C`'s `value` first, then `parent_complex_computation()` would always return that version. Same problem happens when `parent_complex_computation()` is used first, caching `B`'s value.

As answered in the previous question, name mangling (i.e. using `self.__value` instead of `self._value` in `A`) could solve the problem, but in that case every subclass of `A` should redefine both the caching mechanism as its own property and the mangled attribute. Is there a better way to keep the caching mechanism only in class `A` and not duplicating code, while allowing a subclass to both override the cached method `complex_computation` AND call the parent's cached `value`, hence caching both values?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:

- redesign `__init__` to figure out the correct name-mangled version of the name so it is always appropriate for the class it is in
- move the caching behavior into the `complex_computation()` method

I'll show the second method:

```
def complex_computation(self, _cache=[]):
    if not _cache:
        # calculate
        # ...
        # calculated_value = ...
        # 
        # and save
        _cache.append(calculated_value)

    return _cache[0]
```

And then when you want to see your immediate parent's value:

```
def get_parent_calculation(self):
    return super().complex_computation()
```

Comment: But that would actually mean that the caching mechanism is reimplemented in every subclass of `A` which is someting I want to avoid as it would annihilate the purpose of having a superclass taking care of the caching logic.

Comment: @SimoneBronzini:  If you have a chain of classes `A` -> `B` -> `C` -> `D` -> `E` -- how far back do you want to be able to call an ancestor's `complex_method()`?

Comment: a child class should be able to call the parent's `complex_computation()`, no further than that