# Python3 - attach method to class instance

Tags: python-3.x, methods, attributes

I want to add a method to a class. This method contains 'self' which is referred to the class instance itself:

```
def func(self, t):
    return self.b + t

class A:
    pass

a = A()
a.b = 10 
a.foo = func
print(a.foo(3))
```

When I run the code above I get the error:

```
TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'
```

What's wrong with my code?
Thanks!

Comment: You *could*  (not should) do `print(a.foo(a, 3))` but the question is why? What are you really trying to achieve? If this function should have access to the same instance's attribute why not making it a method to begin with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any elegant way to add a method to an existing object in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294458/any-elegant-way-to-add-a-method-to-an-existing-object-in-python)

Comment: thanks. I see that using partial package it works fine. @DeepSpace, what do you mean exactly? Is there a different way to declare methods when external to a class?

Comment: @user1403546 I mean that if `func` should always have access to  `b` attribute of a class `A` instance then why not make it a method of `A`?

Comment: Because I can't modify class A code. And since it's only a matter of one single function even declaring a class which inherited from A seemed too much