# Is it possible to create a method by an argument

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, object

Say I have two functions

```
def do1(x, y):
    return x + y

def do2(x, y):
    return x - y
```

I can create a class like this

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

abc = foo(func=do1)
abc.func(1, 1)  # return 2
abc = foo(func=do2)
abc.func(1, 1)  # return 0
```

Is it possible for me make `abc.func` to be a method rather than an attribute?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, but perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/30294947 is what you're after?

Comment: Go Google "Python instance method."

Comment: `abc.func` is method, not attribute, because you can call it `abc.func()`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to a class like so:

```
def do(self, x, y):
  return x+y

class Foo(object0:
  def __init(self):
    pass

Foo.bar = do

a = Foo()
a.bar(1,2)
out> 3
```

Or to an instance:

```
def do2(x,y):
  return x + y

a = Foo()
a.bar2 = do2
a.bar2(3,4)
out> 7
```