# How to add a dynamic method encoded in a string during class initialization?

Tags: python, methods, dynamic

I am developing an Agent class for an evolutionary algorithm. I need to add a method to it that is generated from a string inherited from the parents.
Here a minimal example

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, s='\tif x > y:\n\t\treturn 1'):
        self.f_template = f'def f(self, x,y):\n{s}'
```

I would like to have the method `self.f(self, x,y)` having `self.f_template` as a function body.
I know I could add it later doing:

```
A = Agent()
exec(A.f_template)
A.f = partial(f, A)

>>> A.f(3,2)
1
```

But is it possible to achieve the same during `__init__()` and not after?

Simply doing the following raises `NameError: name 'f' is not defined`

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, s='\tif x > y:\n\t\treturn 1'):
        self.f_template = f'def f(self, x,y):\n{s}'

        exec(self.f_template)
        self.f = partial(f, self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Python compiler looks at all the l-values in a code block when determining which variables are local, and in this case, `f` is not defined as an `l-value`, so the compiler complains at compilation time rather than at run time. This is not an issue in REPL where every line is compiled separately.

You can instead use the `locals()` dict to access a variable name that is produced dynamically:

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, s='\tif x > y:\n\t\treturn 1'):
        self.f_template = f'def f(self, x,y):\n{s}'
        exec(self.f_template)
        self.f = partial(locals()['f'], self)
```